# Creating extra folder in views with Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, controller, directory

With the default structure:

```
application
- controllers
- - IndexController.php
- models
- views
- - scripts
- - - index
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
```

My IndexController.php in my controllers folder would look like:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action { ... }
```

If I wanted to add a folder inside like this:

```
application
- controllers
- - IndexController.php
- models
- views
- - scripts
- - - index
- - - - posts
- - - - - index.phtml
- - - - - create.phtml
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
```

At what path and what file name do I create the controller for my posts indexAction and createAction? Also, which controller do you extend and how do you name it?

Comment: is `posts` an action? or are your actions `postsIndexAction` and `postsCreateAction`?

Comment: this is applicable in case of `partial views` only

Comment: Yea, I want posts to be an action, I tried using postsIndexAction and postsCreateAction in my Posts_IndexController, but I get Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)'

Comment: ok, I think you just need to understand the directory structure... adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new action (ie: `postsAction()`) you need to create a file that matches the name of your action in the controllers view scripts directory (in this case `postsAction()` exists in `indexController`)

So what you need is this:

```
application
- controllers
- - IndexController.php
- views
- - scripts
- - - index
- - - - posts.phtml
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
```

If you want a structure so that you have `/posts/index` or `/posts/create` then you likely want to have a `postsController` which will contain something that looks like this:

```
application
- controllers
- - IndexController.php
- - PostsController.php
- models
- views
- - scripts
- - - index
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
- - - posts
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
```

If you want `/index/posts-create` as an action in your `indexController` your will need a directory structure like this - **note**: When you use an action with camelCase (`postsCreateAction()`) zend framework converts it to all lowercase with dashes for both the URL and the view scripts.

```
application
- controllers
- - IndexController.php
- models
- views
- - scripts
- - - index
- - - - index.phtml
- - - - create.phtml
- - - - posts-create.phtml
```

You may also want to include a default `ErrorController` - it will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

if you define your actions camelCase like:

```
public function showUsersFromSpaceAction()
{
}
```

- your url will be:
  **index/show-users-from-space**
- and your view script:
  **/views/index/show-users-from-space.phtml**